# Properties disapear after getting the object form the cookiestore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-cookies

I defined a `$routeProvider` that adds `access` to the route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/tracks/:trackTitle/:mediaTitle',
{
    templateUrl: 'views/track-detail.html',
    controller: 'MediaCtrl',
    access: access.user 
    ...
}
```

I am listening to `$routeChangeStart` change event and check that the user can access the page. If the does not I save the route in the cookiestore and load it after the user logs in.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.error = null;
    if (!Auth.authorize(next.access)) {
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn())
      $cookieStore.put('current.user.originalPath', originalPath);
      $location.path('/signup');
    }});
```

The problem is that the `next` object for some reason changes between the put and get from the cookiestore.

Before the `$cookieStore.put` next is:

```
$$route: Object
params: Object
pathParams: Object
__proto__: Object
```

And when I get the object using `$cookieStore.get` the value is

```
params: Object
pathParams: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I am getting the object without $$route object.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try my solution ? Did it help you solve the problem ?

Comment: You were bang on!, Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because values are "JSONified" by Angular before put into the cookie-store.
And Angular's `toJson()` method ignores any properties that start with `$`.
You could use `JSON.stringify()` (not Angular's `toJson()`) to pass the value already "JSONified" or rename the property `$$route` to `route` (or anything that doesn't start with `$`).

---

Unfortunately, since values are "JSONified" it is not possible to store all kinds of preperties.
E.g. functions or non-JSONifiable objects (window, scopes, nodes etc) won't be retained.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/sNFa9/)**.

---

I doubt you actually need the whole `$$route` object, so I suggest you store just the properties you are interested in (e.g. path, pathParams etc).